# Toggle element class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, toggle

I've been having some problem with this code

```
$("#click").bind('mousedown mouseup mouseover', function(e) {
    if(e.type === 'mouseover'){
        $(this).addClass('open'); //works!
    }
    if(e.type === 'mousedown'){
       $(this).removeClass().addClass('closed'); //works!
    }
    if(e.type === 'mouseup'){
       $(this).removeClass().addClass('open');
       // The above line doesn't work :(
    }
});
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/U544t/)**
This code only works for mouseover, mousedown and *NOT* for mouseup. When I uncomment `$(this).removeClass().addClass('open');` the mousedown event stops triggering as well.

Anybody have an idea what the problem may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/U544t/2/

You need to remove the class you don't want, then add the class you do. You were ending up with the div having both `open` and `closed`, thus it was only showing the closed icon.

Comment: In Chrome, doesn't change the icon when mousedown, even though the class changes correctly

Comment: Very true. I've looked into it a bit more, and it seems to be an issue with Chrome/Safari. Suggested fix posted at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/chrome-text-select-cursor-on-drag, but doesn't seem to work for me. Still looking :)

Comment: There seems to be a working implementation here http://candrews.net/sandbox/spryMap/ However I don't see how to implement it, maybe you do : )

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, it seems you could do this a bit more efficiently with [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of doing all the add/remove yourself. And you probably don't need two classes, just a default state, and the .open class to trigger the active upon toggling.

Comment: all that true, but we're trying to get it to work, optimizing it will come soon later : )